# Is there a linter for non-Dart polymer projects?

Tags: dart, polymer

I'm writing a prototype application using Polymer and native js (no Dart). I use VIM as my main editor and I'd like to incorporate a linter that will report A) when a referenced import does not exist or B) when a custom element is not defined anywhere.

Is there a way to use the Dart linter from commandline on non-dart projects?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any Polymer.js linters (as far as I know), but the Polymer team recently came out with [the Web Component Tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester), which could be extended to do such checking dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

[Polymer - Debugging tips and tricks](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/debugging.html) contains some useful info. See especially the `Ungegistered Elements bookmarklet`

Answer (score 0):

Facing the exact same needs, my team wrote their own linter which is now available open source: [polymer-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymer-lint)

Checks currently include:

- component name matches filename
- only one-way binding
- using an element without importing it
- importing an element without using it
- only one component per file
- style tags only inside template elements